# How to fix - 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: php, macos, socks, bad-gateway, patternlab.io

Hello I'm totally clueless here,

I've been working with Patternlab on a local PHP env on mac. I had wifi troubleshooting, I restarted my computer and since then my `localhost:8080` is showing the error below.

```
502 Bad Gateway
Socks5ProtocolException("SOCKS5 mode failure: SocksError('Invalid SOCKS version. Expected 0x05, got 0x47',)",)
```

I'm working on a php local server but I see the error without even lunching it. The error is showing when typing `localhost:8080` in the browser.

(FYI last week I had problem with my PHP memory cache, I needed to updated the `memory_limit = 128M` to `memory_limit = 256M`of the `/etc/php.ini` file can this be relevent to the issue ? It worked fine for 4 days after the change so this may not be the cause of problem but I really don't know what to do! )

Mac info :
macOSMojave 10.14.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved.

I followed theses steps to fix the issue :

- Go to apple icone
- Click system preferences
- Click network -> advanced setting -> proxies
- Uncheck all the options
- Select ok and apply the change restart.